# Java file does not read from the beginning

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

I have a file with the following input:

```
ADD 1 2
SUB 2 1
MUL 2 3
DIV 4 2
QUIT
```

with this part of the code:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
String input = "";
in = new BufferedReader(fin);
while ((input = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    String line = in.readLine();    
    System.out.println(line); // for me to see the output
    out.println(line); // thats for my server
    out.flush(); // for the server
}
```

but it only shows:

```
MUL 2 3
DIV 4 2 
null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader in = null;
String input = "";
in = new BufferedReader(fin);
while ((input = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(input); // for me to see the output
    out.println(input); // thats for my server
    out.flush(); // for the server
}
```

You were reading input from file twice, once in the while statement and once after the while statement.

Comment: there is no `line` variable in your example, so this will cause a compile time error.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen agreed. Edited my post, and +1 for your answer. (for raw speed :) )

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a line from the file twice before you print it's contents:

```
(input = in.readLine())
```

reads a line from the file and stores it in input, then before examining input, you read another line and store it in the line variable:

```
String line = in.readLine();
```

Remove one of the `in.readLine()` calls and it should work fine.